# Why does my powershell prints an error on startup?

Tags: powershell

I get the following error when I load PowerShell Console":

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

All profile locations report false via `TestPath $PROFILE`, as well as locations for Powershell ISE profile files.

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> Test-path $profile.AllUsersAllHosts
False
PS C:\Windows\System32> Test-path $profile.AllUsersCurrentHost
False
PS C:\Windows\System32> Test-path $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
False
PS C:\Windows\System32> Test-path $profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
False
PS C:\Windows\System32> Test-path "C:\Users\bleykekhman\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShelllSE_profile.psl"
False
PS C:\Windows\System32> Test-Path $PSHOME\Microsoft.PowerShelllSE_profile.ps1
False
```

My question is what causes the error message, if I do not have any profile scripts at all?

Comment: Why close, out of curiosity?

Comment: That is certainly odd. Shot in the dark but what does the target for your PowerShell shortcut look like. Is it the same as your last question? Is this the x64 or x86 console? I wonder if you have profiles here maybe? `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

Comment: FWIW I think your problem is clear. Could your replace the image with the actual text though maybe?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run `powershell.exe` from a command prompt?

Comment: @Matt - you are right on the spot. The shortcut was `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -PSConsoleFile "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\tfshell.psc1" -noexit -command ". 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\TFSS` and it is clearly botched. I changed it to `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` and it works fine. Please, arrange your comment as a reply and I will give it the full credit.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - no, I do not. I do not know how I forgot to look at the shortcut, but that was the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have covered the important ground in verifying that you have no profiles present for PowerShell to load. There is one other place that could be configured to load code. I would check your shortcut to PowerShell.exe as see if you have any switches in place like `-File` and `-NoExit`.

I'm sure my shortcut is vanilla since I just reinstalled my OS and updated to v4.0

- Target: `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
- Start In: `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`

Check to see if yours is different.

[AnsgarWiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) was suggesting the same thing from a different approach. Running powershell from cmd prompt with no switches. Which would have led back to the shortcut.

Comment: And it is different, stupid me - should have checked it right away. Seems like installing the Team Foundation Power Tools somehow succeeded to botch the shortcut - clearly missing the name of the script to run and closing single+double quotes. I reset the shortcut and it works fine now.